# How To Add Fabrik Element To Multiple Groups

Tags: php, joomla, content-management-system, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

I use fabrik for my project. In my website there is many forms that have same fields like national code. So I want to add an element like national code to many groups instead of one group. I don't know what to do this and any helps will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you try so far? Please post your trials so we can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Once created, you could simply *copy* the element from a group to others. But it's not effective if there is a lot of groups and if you need to change the element regularly.
This problem bring us to create you own Fabrik form element. As I know, Fabrik doesn't propose an easy way to create a custom element type.
Before developing your own element, you can look in [Fabrik Elements plug-ins](http://fabrikar.com/download?resetfilters=0&clearordering=0&clearfilters=0) if a generic element could be suitable. Otherwise, you can copy the code of an existing similar plugin and customize it yourself.

You can also check in [Fabrik blog](http://fabrikar.com/blog) if in the future a feature of "Custom Elements" is planned

Comment: thanks for your answer. but actually we want to site admin dont challenge to these and simply select all groups he wants and use element in all of those.